# convert an excel file to JSON

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to covert an excel file to specific Jason format.
My Excel file looks like below:
[Excel File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtFgK.png)

I have used pandas library as follows
import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\xcdfr\Desktop\VMtag\vmtag.xlsx', header=1,index_col=None) 
for ind in df.index:
    #print(df['VMName'][ind],"|", df['Scope1'][ind],"|",df['Tag1'][ind], "|",df['Scope2'][ind],"|",df['Tag2'][ind], "|",df['Scope3'][ind],"|",df['Tag3'][ind])
    vmname = df['Name'][ind]
    scop1 = df['Scope1'][ind]
    tag1 = df['Tag1'][ind]
    scop2 = df['Scope2'][ind]
    tag2 = df['Tag2'][ind]
    scop3 = df['Scope3'][ind]
    tag3 = df['Tag3'][ind]
    tagdata = {"external_id": "500cbe10-e7d6-189d-15ae-e60b85326cd3", "tags": [{"scope": scop1, "tag": tag1},{"scope": scop2, "tag": tag2},{"scope": scop3, "tag": tag3}]}
    print(tagdata)
```

Is there a better way so that the JSON format will be as follows:

```
{'external_id': '500cbe10-e7d6-189d-15ae-e60b85326cd3', 'tags': [{'scope': 'Environment', 'tag': 'Production'}, {'scope': 'Application', 'tag': 'App1'}, {'scope': 'Tier', 'tag': 'Web'}]}
{'external_id': '500cbe10-e7d6-189d-15ae-e60b85326cd3', 'tags': [{'scope': 'Environment', 'tag': 'Production'}, {'scope': 'Application', 'tag': 'App1'}, {'scope': 'Tier', 'tag': 'App'}]}
{'external_id': '500cbe10-e7d6-189d-15ae-e60b85326cd3', 'tags': [{'scope': 'Environment', 'tag': 'Production'}, {'scope': 'Application', 'tag': 'App1'}, {'scope': 'Tier', 'tag': 'DB'}]}
{'external_id': '500cbe10-e7d6-189d-15ae-e60b85326cd3', 'tags': [{'scope': 'Environment', 'tag': 'UAT'}, {'scope': 'Application', 'tag': 'App1'}, {'scope': 'Tier', 'tag': 'Web'}]}
{'external_id': '500cbe10-e7d6-189d-15ae-e60b85326cd3', 'tags': [{'scope': 'Environment', 'tag': 'UAT'}, {'scope': 'Application', 'tag': 'App1'}, {'scope': 'Tier', 'tag': 'App'}]}
{'external_id': '500cbe10-e7d6-189d-15ae-e60b85326cd3', 'tags': [{'scope': 'Environment', 'tag': 'UAT'}, {'scope': 'Application', 'tag': 'App1'}{'scope': nan, 'tag': nan}]}
```

I woul like to remove additional "scope" entry if no values in the excel files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this
import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\xcdfr\Desktop\VMtag\vmtag.xlsx', header=1, index_col=None)
tagdata_list = []

for _, row in df.iterrows():
    tagdata = {"external_id": "500cbe10-e7d6-189d-15ae-e60b85326cd3", "tags": []}
    
    for i in range(1, 4):
        scope = row[f"Scope{i}"]
        tag = row[f"Tag{i}"]
        
        if pd.notna(scope) and pd.notna(tag):
            tagdata["tags"].append({"scope": scope, "tag": tag})
    
    tagdata_list.append(tagdata)

for tagdata in tagdata_list:
    print(tagdata)
```